# Is it appropriate to address a college instructor by their first name?

Tags: word-choice

During my tenure at community college, we often addressed our professors (or instructors, whatever you'd like to call them since most didn't have a doctorate) by their first name. Is this the proper thing to do, or should they be addressed as Professor Whomever?

All through elementary school and secondary school we were taught to address the teacher as Mr. This or Mrs. That. In college those rules seemed more relaxed but it still makes me wonder, should you address a college professor with a title or just by their name?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about protocol in a specific relationship rather than the English language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your professor would prefer to be addressed by you. Nearly all the professors that I know prefer to be addressed by their first name when not in very formal situations - both by colleagues and by students. This is certainly true of all the professors who work in my department. This is the situation here in the UK. I can't vouch for professors in the US or other countries, though.

Comment: There's a broad range of preferences. I always told my students to call me "John" because that's my name, but not everybody feels that way. It is always safe to say "Professor X". "Miss/Ms/Mr X" is usually safe, unless you've been told not to use it. "Dr. X" is denigrated, however -- either a PhD is required for the job, in which case everybody's Dr. X and nobody wants to hear about it again, or there are some folks with PhDs and others without, and **nobody** wants to bring that up.

Comment: Nice answers Araucaria and John, I'm in Canada, our school system at the post secondary level is similar to that in the UK. We have colleges of applied arts and technology where diplomas are earned and we have universities where degrees are earned. The one I'm referring to is a college, ie. I received a diploma.